# How would I compress a 1,200 digit long save code

Tags: list

I have 3 lists, one list of 200 first names, one list of 200 Last names, and third list is a list that combines that previous two lists to create a 6 digit code for 1 person and my third list contains 200 randomly generated people 
I.E   152208 = 
52 (Bob) 
and 
108 (Jones) 
so that 152208 would be Bob Jones.

If I were too produce a save-code from this i would get a code that would be 1,200 digits long (6 digits * 200 people) I know it would be possible to get this to 7 digits as 200 * 200 * 200 = 8,000,000 which is 7 digits long.

How would I compress this code by only using non negative whole numbers

Comment: I'm not really sure I know what you are asking, but if you are using a random number generator to create these combinations, why not just save the initial seed?

Comment: I'm looking to shorten the length of the code.